# Wing IDE pytest: how to integrate and use plugins (e.g. xdist)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest, wing-ide, xdist

The testing tool in Wing IDE (Pro) now supports the pytest unit testing framework.

How can I integrate and use pytest plugins, especially xdist? For example, I would like my tests being distributed to multiple CPUs when I run them (triggered from the Wing IDE GUI).

What I have tried:

- I installed pytest and xdist via the package manager
- I added `-n3` ([xdist-specific argument](https://pytest.org/latest/xdist.html#speed-up-test-runs-by-sending-tests-to-multiple-cpus)) to line 333 in the `run_pytest_xml.py` file (on my Ubuntu, this is in `/usr/lib/wingide5/src/testing/runners/run_pytest_xml.py`)

Original:

```
328: result = wingtest_common.XmlTestResult(xmlout)
329: runner = wingtest_common.XmlTestRunner(result)
330: plugin = CPytestPlugin(dirname, result, runner)
331: try:
332:    import pytest
333:    pytest.main(args=['--tb=native', module_fullpath], plugins=[plugin])
```

Changed:

```
333:    pytest.main(args=['--tb=native', '-n3', module_fullpath], plugins=[plugin])
```

This didn't work. When I click on "Run Tests", I get the error message

> Test process suddenly quit while running test_asdf in test_delme.py

NB: without the `'-n3'` in line 333, the test works fine.

Comment: For the record, this doesn't work now but we're working on fixing it w/ OP